# Bot clean written on C++

Tags: c++

First string includes 4 integers: N, M, A, B (1 ≤ N, M ≤ 300, A, B ≤ 1000).
Each next line include M-symbols. Symbol `.` is a clean cell, `*` and `**` are dirty.

I need to find the sum for cleaning if `A` its sum of `**` cell, `B` is sum of `*`.

What I can do better?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main() {
  int n, m, a, b;
  cin >> n >> m >> a >> b;

  vector<string> parquet;

  int itr = 0;

  while (itr < n) {
    string cell;
    cin >> cell;
    parquet.push_back(cell);
    itr++;
  }

  int sum = 0;

  itr = 0;

  while (itr < parquet.size()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < parquet[itr].size(); i++) {
      if (parquet[itr][i] == '*') {
        if (parquet[itr][i + 1] == '*') {
          i++;
          sum += a;
        } else {
          sum += b;
        }
      }
    }

    itr++;
  }

  cout << sum;
}
```

Comment: Any row that ends with "`.*`" is going to cause you to access out of bounds coordinates.

Comment: @twohundredping I can change my if statement to `if (parquet[i][j + 1] != EOF && parquet[i][j + 1] == '*')`, right?

Comment: The quickest change to the current structure would be to change `if (parquet[itr][i + 1] == '*')` to `if(i + 1 < parquet[itr].size() && parquet[itr][i+1] == '*')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refine your algorithm by getting rid of all these counters and `while` loops and replace them with a `for` loop such as this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parquet.size(); i++)
    parquet[i] = ... // do whatever
```

Similarly, you can re-write the summing algorithm as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parquet.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < parquet[i].size(); j++) {
      if (parquet[i][j] == '*') && (parquet[i][j + 1] == '*') {
          j++;
          sum += a;
      else 
          sum += b;
      }
    }
}
```

That said, I notice you're naming your counters as "iter" (which I assume is a short for iterator). Are you trying to access your vector in a typical STL manner (i.e.: using iterators?). If that was your intent, you can try something like:

```
vector<string>::iterator myIterator;
for (myIterator = parquet.begin(); myIterator != parquet.end(); myIterator++)
// Do whatever
```

That is, of course, assuming your procedure works as intended. If not, please state otherwise.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer, and why `for` loop better than `while`?

Comment: Also worth noting C++11's [*range-based for loop*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: @rel1x We generally use `for` loops when we know how many iterations there will be in advance.  In both loops you know the iterations in advance and hence should use a `for` loop.  The `for` loop also allows you to scope the iterating variable to the loop if desired and prevents you from forgetting to increment the counter at the end of the loop (as you can do with a while loop).